# Defining a Jenkins agent using AWS ECR w/o manual credential changing

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecr

I am running Jenkins locally on my machine. I have a pipeline with an agent using a custom Docker image stored in a personal AWS ECR Docker repository. Here is some sample code:

```
pipeline{
  agent {
    docker { 
      image 'image-name:latest' 
      registryUrl 'https://<account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com'
      registryCredentialsId 'aws-ecr-credentials'
      args '-u root:root'
    }
  }

// pipeline steps below
}
```

In this pipeline, I have to pass registry credentials via `registryCredentialsId`. These credential's password is obtained via the following command:

`aws ecr get-login-password --region ${REGION}`

Then, I created a Jenkins username&password credential using "AWS" and this password. Passing this credential in via `registryCredentialsId`, everything works fine.

However, this credential expires after 12hours. I am trying to find a permanent solution that avoids the need to refresh this credential manually.

I have an IAM user that has ECR admin permissions, but it seems that the `registryCredentialsId` will not take it. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

One possible solution (I believe) is a scheduled Jenkins job that rotates the credential. I am trying to avoid this if it is possible as again, this is being run locally, and my machine is not always on.